# Old xSeries 8827 with SLES11, upgrade path suggestions

Tags: mysql, php, ibm

First time poster...

I have three, five year old, IBM 336 servers sitting in a rack behind a hardware firewall.  No load balancing.  They run a web based PHP app on top of Mysql.

Our tech guy suggests moving towards VMWare virtualisation running SLES11 and a mini SAN array for the storage.

However, this won't be for another 12+ months and would ideally have a stepping stone towards this solution.

The single server solution scares me and would like redundancy.

Do you guys have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you should be working towards some form of virtualisation - for resilience and portability at the very least. That said those old servers won't be VMWare-certified, maybe too slow as well - so I'm assuming you'll be getting new server/s?

What I'd suggest is that you get a single server in, maybe a dual-slot Dell/HP/IBM with a single quad-core Xeon 55/56xx and maybe 6GB and a pair of local largish (1TB?) mirrored/R1 SATA disks. Then download the free ESXi 4.1. This will let you start getting up to speed with it all, maybe creating a couple of new servers as VMs and even playing with the Converter application.

Then as plans become firmer you can implement the SAN (I prefer FC over iSCSI but it does get a lot more expensive to be honest) and connect it to the single stand alone ESXi box. Then you can add a second ESXi server and split the VMs manually between them - then when you and your budget is ready get yourself VCenter and some DRS/HA licenses and you'll have the resilience you want. You can then add more CPUs and memory as needed with zero downtime to implement.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for the quick response.  I was surprised to see you suggest a single server solution.  Do you think it's a small risk running everything on one big box? even in the short term? or are things less likely to go 'pop' these days?

Comment: It is a risk yes, but so is diving in with perhaps tens of thousands of dollar's worth of kit and licences. I could be wrong but I read into your question that you may be in a situation with comparatively limited budgets and support staff, in which case a step-by-step transition would be wise. As for kit reliability, well if you're going to spend ~$2k-$3k per CPU in software costs later then I'd suggest it be ran on a machine with quality memory, dual PSUs, on a UPS, mirrored disks etc. i.e. one that is likely to be quite reliable. tbc...

Comment: ...If you want to go with HA/DRS from day one then it'll cost you 2 x $2-4k servers plus 2 x $2-3k ESXi licenses plus a copy of vCenter at ~$3k plus some form of SAN which could be anywhere between $1k and $10k easily - so a lot of 'day one' cost and, again I may be wrong, little ESX/VC experience, limiting the quality of initial deployment. Going step by step means you get to grow your skills as the system does, with no dependency to raise your boss's expectations and pressure. Feel free to come back to me with any further thoughts or questions ok.

Comment: Well, original idea was 2x IBM Express x3550 M3 servers with twin Xeon 4C E5506 cpus, bucket loads of ram (4Gbx14) and then a DS3300 loaded with 8x 300Gb disks.  So, I guess step 1 would be to get one of those x3550 and then build up to the full spec over 12 months.  The spec said VMWare std edition with SLES11 to be in the virtual machine.  Not sure what your thoughts are on this!